# Who titled the poem: "The Dark Night of the Soul"?

Tags: catholicism, mysticism

Wikipedia claims that the Catholic mystic St John of the Cross did not title his own poem: "The Dark Night of the Soul". If St John didn't title it who did?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about literature rather than Christianity.

Comment: @Flimzy We cover all sorts of stuff about prominent Christians both contemporary and historic including trivia about their writings and lives that aren't strictly about Christianity. I don't see why we can't cover this one too.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article ([Dark Night of the Soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Night_of_the_Soul)), to which Constantthin makes reference, says that the author of the poem, Saint John of the Cross, "wrote two book-length commentaries: The *Ascent of Mount Carmel* (*Subida del Monte Carmelo*), and *The Dark Night* (*Noche Oscura*)". So the first part of the title is already expressed by the author himself. As for the second part of the title (*... of the Soul*), Saint John of the Cross introduces the stanzas of his own poem with these words:

> Songs of the soul rejoincing at having achieved the high state of
>   perfection, the Union with God, by way of spiritual negation
>   (Cançiones del alma ques se goca d'auer legado al alto estado de la
>   perfecçion, que es la union con Dios, por el camino de la negaçion
>   espiritual)

Whoever put the two together simply did the obvious ...